# How to array_merge a dynamic array based on one of it's value similarity

Tags: php, arrays, merge, similarity

Good day,

I am retrieving information from various websites using cURL and various parsing techniques. I made
the code so I can, if desired, add additional websites I scan information from.

The information retrieved is as follow :
(Please note that the information may be inaccurate and may not reflect real price/name)

```
Array
(
    [website1.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 5299.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 4499.99
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 3699.99
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 2999.99
                )
        )
    [website2.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sony 3D 60" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [1] => website2.com
                    [2] => 5400.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sony 3D 52" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [1] => website2.com
                    [2] => 4699.99
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sony 3D 46" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [1] => website2.com
                    [2] => 3899.99
                )
        )
)
```

The desired output must be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
            [website1.com] => 5299.99
            [website2.com] => 5400.99
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => 52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
            [website1.com] => 4499.99
            [website2.com] => 4699.99
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => 46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
            [website1.com] => 3699.99
            [website2.com] => 3899.99
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => 40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
            [website1.com] => 2999.99
        )
)
```

Please note that the name may vary so using similar_text is required. Also, some information may not be shown in all websites.
I am aware that only one television name must be choosed, then I will use the one from the most relevent source (website1.com)

Here is the codes I'm trying to make work.

```
<?php
    $_Retreived = array(
        "website1.com" => array(
            array('60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV', 'website1.com', 5299.99),
            array('52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV', 'website1.com', 4499.99),
            array('46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV', 'website1.com', 3699.99),
            array('40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV', 'website1.com', 2999.99)
        ),
        "website2.com" => array(
            array('Sony 3D 60" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA', 'website2.com', 5400.99),
            array('Sony 3D 52" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA', 'website2.com', 4699.99),
            array('Sony 3D 46" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA', 'website2.com', 3899.99),
        )
    );

    $_Prices = array();
    $_PricesTemp = array();
    $_Sites = array("website1.com", "website2.com");

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($_Sites); $i++)
    {
        $_PricesTemp = array_merge($_PricesTemp, $_Retreived[ $_Sites[$i] ]);
    }

    /*
        print_r($_PricesTemp);

        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 5299.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 4499.99
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 3699.99
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [1] => website1.com
                    [2] => 2999.99
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sony 3D 60" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [1] => website2.com
                    [2] => 5400.99
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sony 3D 52" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [1] => website2.com
                    [2] => 4699.99
                )
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Sony 3D 46" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [1] => website2.com
                    [2] => 3899.99
                )
        )
    */

    foreach($_PricesTemp As $_KeyOne => $_EntryOne)
    {
        foreach(array_reverse($_PricesTemp, true) As $_KeyTwo => $_EntryTwo)
        {
            if ($_KeyOne != $_KeyTwo)
            {
                $_Percent = 0;

                similar_text(strtoupper($_EntryOne[0]), strtoupper($_EntryTwo[0]), $_Percent);

                if ($_Percent >= 90) //If names matches 90%+
                {
                    echo "Similar : <b>" . $_KeyOne . "</b> " . $_EntryOne[0] . " and <b>" . $_KeyTwo . "</b> " . $_EntryTwo[0] . " Percent : " . $_Percent . "<br />";

                    $_Prices[] = array();
                    $_Prices[ sizeOf($_Prices)-1 ]['Name'] = $_EntryOne[0]; //Use the product name of the most revelant website (website1.com)

                    foreach($_Sites As $_Site)
                    {
                        if (isset($_EntryOne[ 1 ]) && $_EntryOne[ 1 ] == $_Site) //Check if it contains price from website1.com
                        {
                            $_Prices[ sizeOf($_Prices)-1 ][ $_Site ] = $_EntryOne[ 2 ];
                        }
                        if (isset($_EntryTwo[ 1 ]) && $_EntryTwo[ 1 ] == $_Site) //Check if it contains price from website2.com
                        {
                            $_Prices[ sizeOf($_Prices)-1 ][ $_Site ] = $_EntryTwo[ 2 ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*
        print_r($_Prices);

        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 2999.99
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 3699.99
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 4499.99
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 2999.99
                )
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 3699.99
                )
            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 5299.99
                )
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 2999.99
                )
            [7] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 4499.99
                )
            [8] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 46" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 5299.99
                )
            [9] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 3699.99
                )
            [10] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 4499.99
                )
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => 40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV
                    [website1.com] => 5299.99
                )
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Sony 3D 60" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [website2.com] => 3899.99
                )
            [13] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Sony 3D 60" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [website2.com] => 4699.99
                )
            [14] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Sony 3D 52" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [website2.com] => 3899.99
                )
            [15] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Sony 3D 52" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [website2.com] => 5400.99
                )
            [16] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Sony 3D 46" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [website2.com] => 4699.99
                )
            [17] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Sony 3D 46" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA
                    [website2.com] => 5400.99
                )
        )
    */
?>
```

First of all, the code above isn't working. There must be a logical error somewhere that I can't put my finger on. Also, I don't
believe the code will work in case I add a third website to the listing.

Any ideas guys? I have been on this since this morning.

**Edit 2011-02-16:**

I added a bounty to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this gist is clearer https://gist.github.com/835099

It produced your desired outcome for me.

Comment: @samshull, Thank you for your answer. I will give it a try once I get home.

Comment: @samshull, we aren't far from a solution there. It looks like the `get_common_name` isn't 100% accurate. `$Prices[0]` and `$Prices[1]` got the same name being returned. Also, the **40" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV** isn't found in the final array. It should be even if the price is only found on website1.com. I will check if I can fix it myself.

Comment: @samshull, oh also, one important aspect of the code : it must be able to be dynamic (as much websites as needed). The sources array may have two or more websites. Which push the bar a little higher.

Comment: @Cybrix I could probably fix my code to match your desired result, but if you are going to try to change the question, I won't bother.

Comment: @Samshull, the question remains the same since you may see `I made the code so I can, if desired, add additional websites I scan information from.` from my question already. This may sound unclear but this is what I meant in my third comments.

Comment: @samshull, Thank you. We are almost there! But if I add something like:  `"website3.com" => array(
 array('Sony 40" BRAVIA LX900 3D HDTV', 'website3.com', 999.00)
  ),
  "website4.com" => array(
 array('BRAVIA 40" Sony HDTV', 'website4.com', 888.00)
  ),`, it won't work. Atleast the arrays aren't merging altogether. I'm starting to believe it's too hard to accomplish. I've spent a  a few hours already to try to find a solution. It's very complex.

Comment: @Cybrix you will never be able to accurately compare products that are not the same `'BRAVIA 40" Sony HDTV'` breaks the mold.

Comment: @samshull, I can understand that. But try this: `  "website4.com" => array(
 array('60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV', 'website4.com', 888.00)
  ),` . The 60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV is already matched somewhere in the array and the code still breaks.

Comment: @Samshull, just a little typo though: line 21: `array('32" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV', 'website4` <- should be `website5`

Answer (score 0):

A high level overview should be like this:

- create the end result array $items
- loop through all the found items in all the websites
- for each one, check if it's similar enough to any of the existing item names in $items
- if yes, then add the price to that key, if no then create a new one and add it there

Instead of `similar_text()` you should consider using `levenshtein()` which is similar in practice but quite faster.

Here's some (untested, on the spot) code:

```
$levThreshold = 3 ;

$_Prices = array() ;
foreach ($_Retreived as $website => $websiteItems) {
    $currName = $websiteItems[0] ;
    $currWebsite = $websiteItems[1] ;
    $currPrice = $websiteItems[2] ;

    $foundItemKey = false ;

    //check current price structure. Get $priceData by reference
    //so we can modify it in the loop and keep the changed instead 
    //of the loop copy.
    foreach ($_Prices as &$priceData) {

        if (isset($priceData[$website])) {
            //already done this
            continue ;
        }

        //check if this is the item name we are looping over
        $lev = levenshtein($priceData['Name'], $currName) ;

        if ($lev < $levThreshold) {
            //item exists, add price and break
            $priceData[$website] = $currPrice ;
            $foundItemKey = true ;
            break ;
        }

    }

    //if we haven't found the item key, create a new one
    if (!$foundItemKey) {
        $newItem = array() ;
        $newItem['Name'] = $currName ;
        $newItem[$website] = $currPrice ; 
        $_Prices[] = $newItem ;
    }

}
```

`$levThreshold` is the minimum number of characters that must be different between 2 strings for them to be considered different. You can tweak that accordingly.

Comment: Hi Fanis, I know you answered without testing. But your code isn't working. No error but there must be a logical issue somewhere. I'm trying to fix it but with no success really. Thank you about the levenshtein I wasnt aware of it's existence.

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hi, after looking at your code, it seems that the second foreach isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem cannot be answered using similar_text. You want to match `60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV` with `Sony 3D 60" LX900 HDTV BRAVIA`. However, `60" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV` is actually more similar to `52" BRAVIA LX900 Series 3D HDTV`, only two characters different.

I suspect you'll need a custom handler to match details specific to the products you are trying to match. E.g. for televisions you probably want to match size (`xx"`), and product family (`BRAVIA LX900`).

This doesn't give you a solution to your question, but it is I fear the answer.